# find dtype of root attributes in hdf5 file

Tags: numpy, attributes, hdf5, h5py, dtype

I am attempting to determine the dtype of root-level attributes of an existing hdf5 file using h5py.  I have a crude solution that works but I find it unattractive and hope that there is a better way.  The file root level attributes are shown from the HDF5View program.
[image: This is a screen capture from the hdf5view program]

I need to know that the attribute CHS Data Format has type of 'string length=9 or that Save Point ID is 64-bit floating-point, so that I can properly transform in code.  I can get this information in a brute force  manner, I am hoping there is a cleaner way.

```
hf = h5py.File(hdf5_filename, 'r')

for k in hf.attrs.keys():

     print (k,hf.attrs[k],type(hf.attrs[k]),hf.attrs[k].dtype)
```

which yields:

```
CHS Data Format b'Version_1' <class 'numpy.bytes_'> |S9
Grid Name b'SMA' <class 'numpy.bytes_'> |S3
Latitude Units b'deg' <class 'numpy.bytes_'> |S3
Longitude Units b'deg' <class 'numpy.bytes_'> |S3
Project b'USACE_NACCS' <class 'numpy.bytes_'> |S11
Region b'Virginia_to_Maine' <class 'numpy.bytes_'> |S17
Save Point ID 1488.0 <class 'numpy.float64'> float64
Save Point Latitude b'41.811900' <class 'numpy.bytes_'> |S9
Save Point Longitude b'-71.398700' <class 'numpy.bytes_'> |S10
Vertical Datum b'MSL' <class 'numpy.bytes_'> |S3
```

This gives me the information I need but requires parsing and I would also like to have the additional information that is seen in the image from hdf5View

Even though this is likely not the best/clearest solution, I am posting in case it is of some assistance to others trying to achieve this same goal.

Comment: From a brief look through the documentation, it looks like `hf.attrs.get_id(k).get_type()` returns an object describing the internal data format that you can inspect and extract the info you want (see https://api.h5py.org/h5t.html#h5py.h5t.TypeID).

Comment: The code you posted is the proper way to access attribute names, values, types, and dtypes. What do you mean by "a better way"? Are you printing the data and parsing the strings? If so, there is a better way to do that. FYI, You can shorten your code (a bit) with dictionary `.items()` syntax; e.g., `for k,v in hf.attrs.items():` then using `v` instead of `hf.attrs[k]`.

Comment: Most of the attributes are simple (byte) strings.  `Grid Name b'SMA' <class 'numpy.bytes_'> |S3`.  The key is 'Grid Name', the value is `b'SMA' `(a byte string). then the type, and dtype.  `h5py` is `numpy` oriented, so saves and loads things as `numpy` objects.  There's also a float number.   `hf.attrs[k].item()` extracts these `numpy` classes to plain Python strings and floats.

Comment: What does `hdf5View` show (for one of these attributes)?

Comment: I included an HDF5view screenshot of the attributes in the original post.